# switch function Excel

Tags: excel, excel-formula, switch-statement

I am working on an Excel switch funciton but something is not working.

I have 2 tables. This is my table 1 -

[image]

And this is my Table 2  -

[image]

Now, what is want is - when the table 1 **"Pick value"** Column has a value of `A` it should `enter code here`pick the value from Table 2 column value `A Value` when the value is `B`, it should pick `B Value`, else `C value` from the corresponding field.

That IS WHY I am using this switch query in Excel  -

```
=SWITCH([Pick Value];"A";Table2[A Value];"B";Table2[B Value];Table2[C Value];)
```

But it is not working -

[image]

Anyone knows what I am doing wrong here!

Comment: You are trying to return the whole column into one cell.  You need to include a lookup or filter function to return the correct value.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a `SWITCH` version also using `XLOOKUP`:

```
=XLOOKUP([@ID];Table2[ID];SWITCH([@[Pick Value]];"A";Table2[A Value];"B";Table2[B Value];"C";Table2[C Value]))
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Use FILTER:

```
=@FILTER(CHOOSE(MATCH([@Pick Value];{"A";"B";"C"};0);Table2[A Value];Table2[B Value];Table2[C Value]);Table2[ID]=[@ID])
```

Answer (score 1):

### INDEX/MATCH

If you don't have 365, you can use one of the following formulas.

**Comma**

Array formula (<kbd>CRTL</kbd>+<kbd>SHIFT</kbd>+<kbd>ENTER</kbd>):

```
=IFERROR(INDEX(Table2[@[A Value]:[C Value]],MATCH([@[Pick Value]],LEFT(Table2[[#Headers],[A Value]:[C Value]],1),0)),"")
```

or if using "A","B","C" explicitly (<kbd>ENTER</kbd>):

```
=IFERROR(INDEX(Table2[@[A Value]:[C Value]],MATCH([@[Pick Value]],{"A","B","C"},0)),"")
```

**Semi Colon**

Array formula (<kbd>CRTL</kbd>+<kbd>SHIFT</kbd>+<kbd>ENTER</kbd>):

```
=IFERROR(INDEX(Table2[@[A Value]:[C Value]];MATCH([@[Pick Value]];LEFT(Table2[[#Headers];[A Value]:[C Value]];1);0));"")
```

or if using "A","B","C" explicitly (<kbd>ENTER</kbd>):

```
=IFERROR(INDEX(Table2[@[A Value]:[C Value]];MATCH([@[Pick Value]];{"A";"B";"C"};0));"")
```